# How to apply values from DictProperty after screen is opened in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to collect data from several screens and display on last 'result' screen. For that I want to store values of different widgets in dict property and display them on the screen. The minimum demonstration:

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from collections import defaultdict
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty, DictProperty
)
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import pickle
import kivy


class ResultScreen(Screen):
   
    results = DictProperty({})
    def get_values(self):
        self.results = {1 : -1, 2 : -2}

class PongScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        # print(f'------------{sm.manager}--------------')
        sm.add_widget(PongScreen(name='menu'))      
        sm.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='result')) 
     
        return sm



TestApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory


<ResultScreen>:
    on_enter: self.get_values()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation : 'horizontal'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation : 'vertical'
                Label:
                    text: str(root.results.keys())          
            

<PongScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'To results'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'result'
        Button:
            text: 'Exit'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

I expect to get `[1, 2]` on the text of `Label` on `ResultScreen`. However I am getting empty list. As far as I understand it happens because initialization takes place before execution of `get_values` function. How can I display desired values?

Comment: Did you try with `ids` ?

Comment: @ApuCoder, you mean in py file access all needed widgets and assign values to them? I've considered this, but I wonder if there is more convenient way to do it

Comment: Not sure as there's no reference in your code about how you assign values to `results` in method `get_values`. I only considered `text` updation of the described `Label`.